# Google cloud function which calls Application Integration API trigger

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, application-integration

I am writing a Google cloud function which calls Application Integration API trigger but getting an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1463, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 872, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 870, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 855, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)  # type: ignore[no-any-return]
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/functions_framework/__init__.py", line 134, in view_func
    return function(request._get_current_object())
TypeError: trigger_api() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

Please find the below code:

```
import requests

def trigger_api():
  PROJECT_ID = "test"
  LOCATION = "europe-west1"
  INTEGRATION_ID = "poc-callTrigger"
  TRIGGER_ID = "api_trigger/poc-callTrigger_API_1"
  API_URL =     f"https://integrations.googleapis.com/v2/projects/{PROJECT_ID}/locations/{LOCATION}/integrations/{INTEGRATION_ID}:execute"
  RESOURCE_DATA = {"data": {"id": "12345678"}}

  headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
  request_body = {
  "triggerId": TRIGGER_ID,
  }

  response = requests.post(API_URL, headers=headers, json=request_body)

  if response.status_code == 200:
    return response.json()
  else:
    raise Exception(f"Error triggering API: {response.text}")`
```

I also want to understand if any authentication is required if both cloud function and integration are deployed in the same project. If yes how can I dynamically pass it?

My expectation is to resolve this error, authentication and if there are any changes required in the code.